# ReferenceError: $ is not defined for original flot library

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, flot

everyone, I got this error that inside the original flot.js library.
I wonder what is wrong with this part of the script?
*the error is shwon Fire bug from Firefox
The error msg is:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(document).ready(function () {
```

The line that starts claim to be error code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
$("#flot-placeholder1").UseTooltip();
});
```

And below is the what before the error line:

```
 <script>
//******* 2012 Gold Price Chart
var data1 = [
[gd(2012, 0, 1), 1652.21], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 1742.14], [gd(2012, 2, 1), 1673.77], [gd(2012, 3, 1), 1649.69],
[gd(2012, 4, 1), 1591.19], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 1598.76], [gd(2012, 6, 1), 1589.90], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 1630.31],
[gd(2012, 8, 1), 1744.81], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 1746.58], [gd(2012, 10, 1), 1721.64], [gd(2012, 11, 2), 1684.76]
];
var data2 = [
[gd(2012, 0, 1), 0.63], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 5.44], [gd(2012, 2, 1), -3.92], [gd(2012, 3, 1), -1.44],
[gd(2012, 4, 1), -3.55], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 0.48], [gd(2012, 6, 1), -0.55], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 2.54],
[gd(2012, 8, 1), 7.02], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 0.10], [gd(2012, 10, 1), -1.43], [gd(2012, 11, 2), -2.14]
];
var dataset = [
{ label: "Gold Price", data: data1, points: { symbol: "triangle"} },
{ label: "Change", data: data2, yaxis: 2 }
];
var options = {
series: {
lines: {
show: true
},
points: {
radius: 3,
fill: true,
show: true
}
},
xaxis: {
mode: "time",
tickSize: [1, "month"],
tickLength: 0,
axisLabel: "2012",
axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
axisLabelPadding: 10
},
yaxes: [{
axisLabel: "Gold Price(USD)",
axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
axisLabelPadding: 3,
tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
return $.formatNumber(v, { format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
}
}, {
position: "right",
axisLabel: "Change(%)",
axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
axisLabelPadding: 3
}
],
legend: {
noColumns: 0,
labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
position: "nw"
},
grid: {
hoverable: true,
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: "#633200",
backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
},
colors: ["#FF0000", "#0022FF"]
};
```

=================UPDATE=====================================================
Hi, everyone. thanks for the answer!
here is the order I load the script (load correctly because I test it in the DW CS4
1. jquery-1.8.3.min.js
2. jquery.flot.min.js"
3. jquery.flot.time.js"
4. jquery.flot.symbol.js
5. jquery.flot.axislabels.js
6. jshashtable-2.1.js
7. jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min.js

So I consider the order should not be a problem, its following the tutorial told me to do here:
http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-flot-tutorial-how-to-make-a-jquery-flot-line-chart.html

Also I found these code was put a stop on by Firefox/firebug, maybe it helps. The stop was put in front of the 2nd line of the code--> '$(this).bind("plot...'.

```
$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
$(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
if (item) {
if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
previousLabel = item.series.label;
$("#tooltip").remove();
var x = item.datapoint[0];
var y = item.datapoint[1];
var color = item.series.color;
var month = new Date(x).getMonth();
//console.log(item);
if (item.seriesIndex == 0) {
showTooltip(item.pageX,
item.pageY,
color,
"<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(USD)");
} else {
showTooltip(item.pageX,
item.pageY,
color,
"<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(%)");
}
}
} else {
$("#tooltip").remove();
previousPoint = null;
}
});
};
```

Thanks.

Further Question for kevin is asked under comment for his answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
$(document)
```

`$` is not defined. That means you either aren't including jQuery, are including it too late, or are using `$.noConflict()` incorrectly.

More specifically, `$ === undefined`, and undefined is not a function and therefore can't be executed.

Comment: Hi, Kevin, thanks for the answer, but what does it mean 'or are using $.noConflict() incorrectly'? I saw this function appear in seveal different places in the script, but I do not know how could they be incorrect since its the original code?

Answer (score 3):

That means you need to include jQuery in your HTML page. Add this (or a different reference to the jQuery library) before you run your `$(document).ready` line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

`$` refers to the jQuery library, which needs to be available before you use it.

In addition, you need to load the flot library **after** you load the jQuery library. flot is a jQuery plugin, so it depends on the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks lan, I added further detail to aid you solving this issue. Plz let me know if you want to have further request.